# Error - Using the generic type 'System.Collection.Generic.List<T> requires '1' type arguments

Tags: c#

Hi I am getting this error on the following code, the code which is highlighted with 2 * in front. Can anyone pls help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;


namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
class SStructure
{

    **List<Property.Prop, List<Property.AddProp>> propset;**


    public SStructure( List<Property.Prop, **List<Property.AddProp>> propset**)
    {

        this.propset = propset;

    }


}
```

}

Comment: The error is very descriptive. You are trying to pass 2 type arguments to a `List<T>` which only takes 1 type argument.

Comment: There is no List<T1, T2> that I'm aware of.  Perhaps you want a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)?

Comment: Can  you pls suggest how can i do this? I am not sure as I am new to C#.

Comment: @us111: What are you trying to achieve? More description of what problem you are trying to solve would help

Comment: Perhaps you want to use a different data structure? You can key a List<Property.AddProp> to a Property.Prop using a Dictionary<Property.Prop, List<Property.AddProp>>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic class `List<T>` only has one type parameter - you are trying to pass two.